# VBA: change file connection based on named range

Tags: vba, excel

---

First here is the code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim oldfilestring As String
Dim filestring As String

Set rng = Range("Files")

oldfilestring = "File A"

For Each cell In rng
    filestring = cell.Value
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldfilestring, NewName:=filestring, Type:=xlExcelLinks

CopyPasteFilteredData
    oldfilestring = filestring
Next cell

End Sub
```

- Where my range is a set list of files that I imported into column A:A

Where I am having trouble is on line "oldfilestring = 'File A', sometimes the first file is not "File A" - how do I edit this to made it the first file in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rng` corresponds to your list of files then you can set the first cell in the list as your `oldfilestring` string

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim oldfilestring As String
Dim filestring As String

Set rng = Range("Files")

oldfilestring = rng.Cells(1, 1).value

For Each cell In rng
    filestring = cell.Value
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldfilestring, NewName:=filestring, Type:=xlExcelLinks

CopyPasteFilteredData
    oldfilestring = filestring
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Comment: If you found my answer helpfull, please mark it as the answer to your question by clicking on the checkmark!